# How can I use javascript for opening a new html after a materialize modal has opened for 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, materialize

I am creating a 'login' page, and I have it so that once the user presses the login button, a modal appears that says "Login Successful". What I want it to do, is after the modal appears for 3 seconds, it automatically opens up my profile.html page.

I'm using the Materialize Modals.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='input-field col s12'>
    <input class='validate' type='email' name='email' id='txtEmail' />
    <label for='email'>Enter your email</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='input-field col s12'>
    <input class='validate' type='password' name='password' id='txtPassword' />
    <label for='password'>Enter your password</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col s12">
    <button data-target="modal2" id="btnLogin" type='submit' class='col s12 btn startup modal-trigger'>Login</button>
  </div>
<!-- Login SUCCESS Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content" id="modal2content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s5 offset-s4">
        <i class="success large material-icons">check</i>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="success">Login Successful!</p>
 </div>
```

I already have the Materialize javascript to run the modal:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });`

But I need to be able to open profile.html after the modal has run.
Any ideas or links or other ways to set it up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap modal has [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events). You can use the `shown_bs_modal` event.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {

  // Wait 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {

    window.location.href = 'url_of_your_profile_page';

  }, 3000);
});
```

Once the modal is shown, wait 3 seconds then navigate to your profile page url.

**Edit:** As it seems you are using materialize modals and not bootstrap modals, here is a new version. Materialize modals have a `onOpenEnd` event.

```
$('.modal').modal({

  onOpenEnd: function() {

    // Wait 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {

      window.location.href = 'url_of_your_profile_page';

    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Earlier versions of the library were apparently using `ready` instead of `onOpenEnd`. See the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#options) for the latest version.

Proof of concept example: fire an alert once the modal has been shown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.modal').modal({
  
    onOpenEnd: function() {
    
      alert('modal has opened');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will I have to change all of my Materialize modals over to bootstrap to use this?

Comment: Well, you tagged your question with `bootstrap-modal` so I thought that's what you were using. Anyway, materialize modals also have events. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much! this is perfect. worked wonderfully. I'm sorry I tagged the question with bootstrap, I couldn't find a materialize modal tag.